# Merge e-mail addresses on iCloud

Tags: email, icloud, macos

I have made a mistake. I'm a developer and while testing iCloud I made an @me.com (let's call it dummy@me.com) account. Now I am setting up iCloud on all my devies and would like to use my original Apple ID which I use my Gmail for.
To use Notes and Mail in iCloud I need a @me.com mail and I would like to use the one I made earlier (dummy@me.com) but I am told this e-mail is already registered - that's true, it's mine. My original Apple ID has another @me.com e-mail attached to it (let's call it placeholder@me.com).

Does anyone know if there is a way to delete dummy@me.com and recreate it on my original Apple ID or attach it to my original Apple ID?

Comment: The Apple ID/iCloud management tools are so lacking it's ridiculous. Don't expect to be able to do anything deemed "complicated".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite some positive reports in September, [it looks like](http://www.macrumors.com/2011/10/13/apple-not-offering-apple-id-merging/) you won't be able to merge Apple IDs.
You can, however, set up iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad, Mac or PC to [use two different accounts for iCloud and purchases](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4895):

> #### iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch:
>
> When you first set up your iOS 5 device, enter the Apple ID you want
>   to use with iCloud. If you skipped the setup assistant, sign in to
>   **Settings > iCloud** and enter the Apple ID you’d like to use with
>   iCloud. In **Settings > Store**, sign in with the Apple ID you want to use
>   for store purchases (including iTunes in the Cloud and iTunes Match).
>   You may need to sign out first to change the Apple ID.
>
> #### Mac:
>
> Enter the Apple ID you want to use for iCloud in **Apple () menu >
>   System Preferences > iCloud**.  Enter the Apple ID you want to use for
>   store purchases (including iTunes in the Cloud and iTunes Match) in
>   **iTunes > iTunes Store**.
>
> #### PC:
>
> Enter the Apple ID you want to use for iCloud in **Control Panel >
>   Network > Internet > iCloud**.  Enter the Apple ID you want to use for
>   store purchases (including iTunes in the Cloud and iTunes Match) in
>   **iTunes > iTunes Store**.
>
> > Note: You can switch the Apple ID you use for
> >     store purchases at any time. However, you can only change the account
> >     you use for any iTunes in the Cloud features once every 90 days. See
> >     this article for more information.